# Unique ID Value To a Cloned Input field Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass a unique id value to an input field array every time i clone a set of input fields by clicking a button. I'm getting the unique id to pass as the value but it keeps changing all input fields to the same number.

For example when i click the clone button the input field value becomes 001

When i click the button again, the first AND second group of input fields becomes 002 instead of being 001 and 002.

Here's the jsfiddle
    https://jsfiddle.net/jdarville/mbfjmd02/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
  var s = String(this);
  while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
  return s;
}


var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
var c = 9;
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        c++;
        $(wrapper).append('<div><label><span>Template Id :</span><input type="text" name="templateid[]" id="templateid[]"></label><br><label><span>UNC Path :</span><input type="text" name="uncpath[]" id="uncpath[]"></label><br><label><span>Username :</span><input type="text" name="username[]" id="username[]"></label><br><label><span>Password :</span><input type="text" name="password[]" id="password[]"></label><br><label><span>Name :</span><input type="text" name="scantoname[]" id="scantoname[]"></label><a href="#" class="remove_field btn btn-primary">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box


    <!--add input value to 'how many field-->
$.each($('input[name="howmany[]"]'), function() {


    $(this).val(x);
});




    <!--add input value to 'templateid field-->
  $('input[name="templateid[]"]').each(function() {
 $(this).val((c).pad(3));
}); 



    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove     text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
});
<script>
```

Comment: That's because you are updating all input field values with the .each function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserted the counter var x into your string

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/u93v63vb/

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><label><span>Template Id :</span><input type="text" name="templateid'+x+'" id="templateid'+x+'"></label><br><label><span>UNC Path :</span><input type="text" name="uncpath'+x+'" id="uncpath'+x+'"></label><br><label><span>Username :</span><input type="text" name="username'+x+'" id="username'+x+'"></label><br><label><span>Password :</span><input type="text" name="password'+x+'" id="password'+x+'"></label><br><label><span>Name :</span><input type="text" name="scantoname'+x+'" id="scantoname'+x+'"></label><a href="#" class="remove_field btn btn-primary">Remove</a></div>'); //add
```

... changed this so you get padded results:

```
 $('input[name="templateid'+x+'"]').each(function() {
     $(this).val((x).pad(3,0));
 });
```

and changed first fields into `id1` and `name1` and base value `001`

Comment: One last thing, how can i post the data now with +x+ ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/zg1lph3sSUHyDmMDsny2?p=preview This demo will send all field data.

Comment: zer00ne, can you show the code within the php file?

Comment: @JohnDarville it's a test server http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php and unfortunately, I'm a front-end developer, I don't know PHP very well. Besides, that's another question entirely. Good luck, sir. ;-)